# AJAX update database on click within the while loop

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress, while-loop

I am developing a plugin for WordPress system for some custom media review purpose. I have setup most of the things but few more.

Currently I stuck on the part to update database on click ( onlink ) to update table value using AJAX. Refer below code. It has while loop and I want to use AJAX within the loop to update media status. I am not sure is this the right way or there is another simple way to make it happen. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$media_item = mysql_query($media_sql);

if ($media_item) {

echo '<ul class="rm-media-list">'; 

    while ($media = mysql_fetch_array($media_item)) {

        $m_uid = $media['user_id'];
        $m_uname = $media['user_login'];

        $media_class = new q2a_review_media;
        $thumb_path = $media_class->rm_thumbnail_url($pid,$m_uid);
        $media_url = $media_class->rm_media_url($pid,$m_uid);
        $mediaid = $media['id'];
        $image_name = $media['image_name'];                                

        echo '<li>';
        echo '<span class="rm-media-user"><a href="'.admin_url( 'user-edit.php?user_id=' . $m_uid, 'http' ).'">',$m_uname,'</a></span>';
        echo '<a href="'.$media_url.$image_name.'" rel="lightbox['.$pid.']" title="Post: '.$pid.' |  '.$ptitle.' | Image: '.$image_name.' | by: '.$m_uname.' " ><img src="'.$thumb_path.$image_name.'" alt="'.$media['image_name'].'" width="56" class="rm-thumbs-list" /></a>';
        echo '<span class="rm-action-links"><a href="#" id="approve-'.$mediaid.'" >Approve</a> | <a href="#" id="delete-'.$mediaid.'" >Delete</a></span>';                            
        echo '</li>';
    }

} else {

    echo 'No media found';

}

echo '</ul>';                        
?>
```

**Database Table:**
[image]

**My Plugin Page Output**
[image]

In above image you can see link called `Approve` | `Delete` Here I want to make interaction with database using ajax. When admin click on `Approve` it will update value from 0  to 1 in `status` column and when `Delete` than it will delete the row and images from the directory. Hope I posted enough data to understand. If not please let me know I will try to add some more information.

Million thanks.... :)

Comment: What have you tried to make the AJAX request work? I'm not seeing any ajax logic within the loop.

Comment: I don't even know how to start within the loop. I am to seeking full working code but need some start up path with some explanation than I can start to work on. I have check couple of videos but none of them showing how to use within the loop and without form only for links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your statement `echo '</ul>';` needs to be in the `if` part of the loop.

Your AJAX code doesn't have to be inside the while loop. Here is how you can manipulate your code to make an AJAX request.

Let's first modify your `<a>` tag slightly:

```
<a href="#" class="approve-button" id="'.$mediaid.'">Approve</a>
```

This change allows you to have a group of buttons with `class="approve-button"` and `id="the id of the item you want to approve"`

Now, we can use some JavaScript to make an AJAX request. For convenience, I will use jQuery to make this request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Attach an onclick handler to each of your buttons that are meant to "approve"
$('.approve-button').click(function(){

   //Get the ID of the button that was clicked on
   var id_of_item_to_approve = $(this).attr("id");

   Make an AJAX request
   $.ajax({
      url: "some-page.php", //This is the page where you will handle your SQL insert
      type: "post",
      data: "id=" + id_of_item_to_approve, //The data your sending to some-page.php
      success: function(){
          console.log("AJAX request was successfull");
      },
      error:function(){
          console.log("AJAX request was a failure");
      }   
    });

});

</script>
```

As far as `some-page.php` goes, this is what you need to do:

- Have your SQL statements that will make the changes to he database
- To access the ID attached to the approve button that was clicked, you can use the `$_POST` array since the AJAX request was of type "post". Specifically, this is where your ID is stored: `$_POST['id']`

---

FYI: To import jQuery on your page, you can use:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: This is working for non WordPress system but not with WordPress. I mean things fine but when ajax calling the page it is not considering the code

Comment: Not sure what the problem could be. I've never used Wordpress

Comment: No problem still selecting your answer as it works for normal ajax call. Thanks a lot.